# How to get Pull Request Message Body

Tags: git, jenkins, github

With `git log` command I can successfully get a Github Pull Request number. 
Now, with the Pull Request number known, I would like to go ahead and query the message (a comment) posted with the PR (the PR message is displayed under the `Conversation` tab). Here is an example of PR with a message posted:

[image]

https://github.com/podgorskiy/ALAE/pull/11

How to query the PR message (aka PR comment) from a command line (with `curl` or `git` or something else)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the PR message using `curl`

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:pull_number | jq '.body'
```

To get the PR comments using `curl` use [Issue Comments API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/) as per the [docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/) :

> The Pull Request API allows you to list, view, edit, create, and even merge pull requests. **Comments on pull requests can be managed via the Issue Comments API.**

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:pull_number/comments | jq '. [] | .body'
```

Note: You can process the `JSON` data received from the `curl` request using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), a command-line `JSON` processor.